# How can I capture a size 1 city without destroying it?

Tags: freeciv

Whenever I try to capture an empty size 1 city by entering it, the city gets destroyed. If I want to capture the city instead of destroying it, I send in a diplomat/spy to bribe the city. Once bribed, the city becomes mine. Is there a way to capture a size 1 city without bribing it?

Answer (score -1):

You can't. It's very very simple.